# Runtime.exec() won't finish properly

Tags: java, servlets, runtime, exec

I've created a WebApp that relies on external scripts to gather query request by the user (internal software). I've tested, with sucess, the WebApp off the glassfish server provided by netbeans but whenever I try and upload my App to a third party server (Apache Tomcat) I run into the issue of the process.getRuntime exitValue never being written and the WebApp never gets to the result page....

This is the code that I have implemented so far:

**Update --> The code now works after reading both stderr and stdin:**

```
        pd = new ProcessBuilder("runscript.bat");
        pd.redirectErrorStream(true);
        process = pd.start();


        StreamGobbler inputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "Input");
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(),"Error");

        errorGobbler.start();
        inputGobbler.start();

        int exitVal = -1;

        try {
            exitVal = process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //log Error
        }

class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
     OutputWriterReader outWR = new OutputWriterReader();
     BufferedWriter deadWriter;
     InputStream is;

// reads everything from is until empty. 
StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) {
    this.is = is;
    createWatch(type);
}
// depending on if Error stream or Input Stream
private void createWatch(String type){
    try {

        if(type.equals("Error"))
            deadWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("StdError.txt"));
        else if(type.equals("Input"))
            deadWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("StdInput.txt"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //log Error
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {            
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(this.is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line=null;

        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            deadWriter.append(line);

        deadWriter.flush();
        deadWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //log Error
    }
}
```

}

Any Suggerstions? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: don't know, because I can's see any code for Process/ProcessBuider, but for <= Java6 you have to use whatever.close() in the finally{..} block

Comment: I tried that as well, still gets stuck in this section of the code

Answer (score 3):

The process may not be complete when you call exitValue() on it.

Before process.exitValue() call add:
process.waitFor();

Comment: I added the process.waitFor() but it still hangs on the server yet runs to completion on my local machine